# How can I specify shards number/zookeeper path in solrconfig.xml?

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrcloud, solr4

In solr 4 [tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) example show that I can start solr from start.jar.

```
java -Djetty.port=7574 -DzkHost=localhost:9983 -jar start.jar
```

I want to start it with my tomcat from war file(I have configured initctl daemon so it will be easier and more stable), therefor I have to specify these cloud parameters somewhere in configuration files, solr.xml or solrconfig.xml. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post exactly how you solved this? Did you specify numShards in [yourtomcatdir]/solr/solr.xml, or load numShards into a different config file and push that to zookeeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in [yourtomcatdir]/solr/solr.xml -- in this file at a top-level node (solr) you can have a zkHost attribute where you list coma-separated zookeeper instances (host:port) to connect to for getting core configuration.